# Spelling of first-year/first-year’s

Tags: spelling

In a sentence like:

> I teach programming to first-years.

What’s the correct spelling for the last plural? *first-years*, *first-year’s*, ...?

I don’t know how to pluralize, hyphenate, and/or apostrophize.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is *freshman*; *I teach programming to **freshman**.*

Comment: A good rule of thumb is: **Plurals don't take apostrophes.**  If you follow that rule, you'll be correct 99.9% of the time.

Comment: You've already got a good answer before, but on a more general note, this might help: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/apostrophe

Comment: The best word choice could depend on where you are (for example, I'd expect *freshmen* or *first-year students*, or informally *freshies*). A Wikipedia article, [Student orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student_orientation), also mentions "In Canada, first year students are called "Frosh" or "first years." The terms "freshies" and "freshers" are also emerging. In the United States, first year university students are typically referred to as freshmen."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not use *first-years* because we don't know what it really means.
If you meant students, I would go with:

> I teach programming to **first-year** students. (hyphen optional)

This pushes the plurality onto *student*, which is easy to manage.
But if you insist on using *first-years* of some form, I would use:

> I teach programming to **first-years**. (hyphen optional)

In context it is just plural. No apostrophe because it is not modifying anything.

Comment: Hi, user3169. You said you would not use first-years and your example sentence is the same one as in the question.

Comment: @Rathony Somehow what I wrote was not what I intended to write. I edited the answer according to what I meant to say. Thanks for catching my lapse.